# Changing the format of date

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datetime

I have a DateTime variable (say, timestamp) that holds a date in its usual format like this:

```
11/1/2011
```

This variable is used to build a SQL command. The Oracle database only accepts dates in the format

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

How can I manipulate my variable to store the date in this format?

Comment: Is the variable a `DateTime` or a `string`? `DateTime`s "hold" their dates as 64-bit integers, not in a textual format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you send the date as string in the SQL command.

```
DateTime date = ...your object...;
string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

If it´s in string format, then you need to parse it first. It´s hard to see from your string if it´s day/month/year or month/day/year.

But you could do something like this:

```
string sDateTime = "11/1/2011";
DateTimeFormatInfo format = new DateTimeFormatInfo();
format.ShortDatePattern = "dd/MM/yyyy"; // or MM/dd/yyyy
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(sDateTime, format);
string formattedDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Comment: Thanks. This solves my problem. I know this is an easy fix though, and I will eventually incorporate parameterized queries.

Comment: The available format strings like Mikael's "yyyy-MM-dd" for .Net are documented here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 8):

**Don't format the date to include it in SQL at all.**

Use a [parameterized query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oracleclient.oraclecommand.parameters.aspx), and then just include the value as a parameter. That way you don't have to get any formatting right at all.

You should use parameterized queries for *all* data - aside from formatting, it also protects you from SQL injection attacks.

Getting a date/time format which works for the particular installation of Oracle you're using right now is *not* the right fix. Do it properly: avoid including data in your code (the SQL).

---

On a different matter, your question is making incorrect assumptions to start with. A `DateTime` variable doesn't hold value in a "usual format" at all, any more than an `int` holds a decimal representation or a hex representation of a number. `DateTime` doesn't store text internally at all - it stores a number of ticks. How it is formatted when you call `ToString` depends on all kinds of cultural aspects. It's worth separating the notion of the fundamental value represented by a type from the *formatted* string representation you might happen to obtain by calling `ToString`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this and try to incorporate it into my code

Comment: +1 Brilliant! This is by far the smartest, easiest way to go.

Comment: Good answer Jon, but I think it's worth pointing out the existence of custom formats that can be passed to `DateTime.ToString`. It might help clear up the confusion the OP is experiencing.

Comment: @Jason: I would have done so if that were the best way to go. It's probably the *fastest* way that the OP can get to "working" code at the moment, but I don't want to encourage bad practice by giving a short-term fix when the more appropriate solution is parameterized queries. Oh, and there are already three other formatting answers, so it wouldn't be adding much there, either :)

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Good point. I'll keep that idea in mind in the future when answering questions myself.

Comment: @Jason: Well, don't take it as gospel or anything. On any other given day I *might* have included the formatting bit :) (as well, of course... never instead).

Answer (score 1):

```
var dt = DateTime.Now;
var formatted = dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
string oracleTimeFomatDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
```