# in oracle db format of date 04-DEC-20 while displaying in console shows date like 04-09-2020

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, datetime

i need to fetch last modified date of item in table(oracle db).
in db format of modified date=04-DEC-20
while displaying in console modified date=04-09-2020

c# code to fetch modified date

```
             string connString =DBUtils.GetDBConnection();
      
                        
            OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection();

            conn.ConnectionString = connString;

            string sql = "select LASTMODIFIED , name from v_vname where name in('hector')";
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();


           
                // Set connection for command.
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = sql;
                conn.Open();
        using (DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {

                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    
                    int date = reader.GetOrdinal("LASTMODIFIED"); // 0

                    var LASTmTime = reader.GetValue(0);
                 Console.WriteLine("modifieddate:" + LASTmTime);
                  }
              }
         }
```

Comment: You might want to check two things: TO_CHAR function and it's format masks and/or NLS settings. However, the main thing would be - if you have date/timestamp in DB, better to read those as temporal in the app and then format those accordingly only when you are outputting those

Comment: Both c# and Oracle use the same DateTime format (a number) to store the date.  When debugging in c# you see the default method VS uses to display the date.  When displaying a ToString() default method is used,   So the dates are exactly the same in Oracle and c# they are just being displayed in a different format.

Comment: What is the data type of LASTMODIFIED column?  If it is DATE, then your assertion that its format is <whatever> is incorrect. DATE datatypes have a consistent, internal, binary formatting.  What you _see_ and _report_ as <whatever> is merely a character representation of the date, resulting from implicit or explicit use of TO_CHAR().  If, however, the data type of LASTMODIFIED is _not_ DATE, then you have a serious design flaw.  Dates should _always_ be typed as DATE or TIMESTAMP,   See more at https://edstevensdba.wordpress.com/2011/04/07/nls_date_format/

Comment: @jdweng That is incorrect. In Oracle, a `DATE` data type is [stored in a table as 7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/) representing century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second.

Comment: @MT0 : It is still a number and the driver does the translation between the database and Net which has nothing to do with the question.  The question has to do with displaying the number.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can format a `date` as a string with `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(lastmodified, 'dd-mm-yyyy') as last_modified, name 
from v_vname 
where name = 'hector'
```

Side note:  `name in ('hector')` is simpler phrased `name = 'hector'`.

Answer (score 0):

It's elegant when you use .ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") in C#

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    int date = reader.GetOrdinal("LASTMODIFIED"); // 0
    var LASTmTime = reader.GetValue(0).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Console.WriteLine("modifieddate:" + LASTmTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`DATE` data-type values in Oracle are binary values [consisting of 7-bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568193/) (which are always century, year-of-century, month, day, hour, minute and second).

What you are seeing when you say the format is `DD-MON-RR` is the user interface you are using formatting the binary value as something that you, the user, will understand and for SQL/Plus (and SQL Developer and others) this will be based on the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter and the [default `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50164234/1509264) depends on which territory you say you are using when you setup the database.

What you need to do, is the output a string representation of the `DATE` formatted according to your requirements. You can either do this in SQL and use `TO_CHAR` to format the string:

```sql
SELECT TO_CHAR( LASTMODIFIED, 'DD-MM-YYYY' ) AS last_modified,
       name
FROM   v_vname
WHERE  name = 'hector'
```

Or [could do it in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4629347/changing-the-format-of-date):

```cs
DateTime LASTmTime = reader.GetValue(0);
Console.WriteLine("modifieddate:" + LASTmTime.toString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```